# Expand div based on content using CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz6Ja/)

[Full Screen JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz6Ja/embedded/result/)

Before I ask my question I want to let you know that what you see on JSFiddle is not accurate to what you see on a regular browser. You don't actually have to scroll on an actually browser and the footer is fixed position. You have a header and a fixed footer and the content div is 950px that fills the gap between the header and footer with no scroll.

That being said you can see the black content div in the middle between the header and footer. My issue is that I set it to 950px and it fills the gap between the header and footer. I want my div to expand by scrolling if the content on the page is greater than the size of 950px that I set. Is there any way of doing that or do I just need to directly set my div for each page based on how much content I add? I only want the scroll feature to add if it goes over the 950px.

HTML:

```
<body>
          <body>
                <div id="page">

                        <div id="header">


                        </div>




                        <div id="main">
                        </div>




                        <div id="footer">
                                <h4>WNG Product Development Engineering (US)</h4>
                                <a href="">Circuit</a>
                                <a href="">Contact Us</a>
                        </div>

                </div>
        </body>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body
{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
        font-size:1em;
}
#page
{
        height:100%;
        min-width:960px;
}
#header
{
        background-color:#115EA2;
        height:100px;
        width:100%;
}
#main
{
        width:1300px;
        background-color:black;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px 20px 40px 20px;
        color:#115EA2;
        text-decoration:none;
        height:950px;
}
#footer
{
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0;
        height: 35px;
        background-color:#115EA2;
}

#footer h4
{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
        float:left;
        color:#fff;
        margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}
#footer a
{
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
        float:right;
        color:#fff;
        margin:10px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;

}

#footer a:active {color:#fff;}
#footer a:hover {color:#fff;}
#footer a:visited {color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `#main { min-height: 950px; }`?  I updated your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Bz6Ja/1/) with a different height and added some content so you can see that a scroll bar appears on the side.  You'll probably want to add a margin to the bottom of `#main` that is the same height as your fixed footer.

Comment: What is that min-height actually does? If I have content that goes past the 950px mark what will happen then? @hungerstar

Comment: It will do exactly what your asking.  Along with doing exactly what itself says.  It sets a minimum height for a block element.  The block element can be larger (i.e. content stretches it) but it will have at the bare minimum the `min-height` that you set for it just in-case your content doesn't fill it to that `min-height`.

Comment: ohhh I see that makes sense. I am still in the learning process of html and css haha. Thank you so much though!!